# Implementing methods: Writing two classes, one with a main, other with not

Tags: java, class

I'm suppose to write a class with the following.

- First Name
- Last Name
- ID
- Score1
- Score2
- Score3
- Average
- Grade  (for A, A-, B+, ...E).

All the data members are suppose to be private.

Below this is what I have and I named the class, Student.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Student {
       private String fname;
        private String lname;
        private int id;
        private int score1;
        private int score2;
        private int score3;
        private double average;
        private String grade;

        public void readInfo()
        {
            Scanner k = null;
            k = new Scanner (System.in);

            System.out.println ("Please enter the first name: (Enter John as first name and Doe as last name to stop) ");
            fname = k.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter the last name: ");
            lname = k.next();
            if (fname.equalsIgnoreCase("John")&&lname.equalsIgnoreCase("Doe"))
            System.exit(0);
            System.out.println("Please enter the student ID: ");
            id = k.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please enter the first score: ");
            score1 = k.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please enter the second score: ");
            score2 = k.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please enter the third score: ");
            score3 = k.nextInt();
        }

        private void computeAverage()
        {
            average = (score1+score2+score3)/3;

        }
        private void computeGrade()
        {
            if (average>=90&&average<=100)
                grade = "A";
            else if (average>=80&&average<=89.9)
                grade = "B";
            else if (average>=70&&average<=79.9)
                grade = "C";
            else if (average>=60&&average<=69.9)
                grade = "D";
            else 
                grade = "F";
        }

        private String getName()
        {
            return fname + " " + lname;
        }
        private double getAverage()
        {
            return average;
        }
        public void printAll()
        {
            System.out.printf("%-9s%-10s %-9s %-3s %-3s %-3s %-5s  %-5s", "LastName","FirstName","ID","S1","S2","S3","AVG","GRADE");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.printf("%-9s%-9s  %-9d %-3d %-3d %-3d %-3.2f%-2s",lname,fname,id,score1,score2,score3,average,grade);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
```

The problem I'm having is how to actually get the information to display on the console. I went ahead and created an instance and called it Averages of the Student class (the class thats listed above.)

Here is what I have of the other class called 'Averages'. I'm lost on what to do. First time actually in Java, only been studying it for two weeks. My book does not clarify anything. So? I assume I'm still learning the ropes and feeling annoyed, I cannot figure this probably (easy) part out. Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Averages {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner k= new Scanner(System.in);

        Student[] students = new Student[36];

        Student st, st2;
        st = new Student();
        st2 = new Student();





        System.out.printf("%-9s%-10s %-9s %-3s %-3s %-3s %-5s  %-5s", "LastName","FirstName","ID","S1","S2","S3","AVG","GRADE");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
        //System.out.printf("%-9s%-9s  %-9d %-3d %-3d %-3d %-3.2f%-2s",lname,fname,id,score1,score2,score3,average,grade);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code to help you.

It mainly populates the array with students' data, and computes and prints the class average :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

int classSize = 36;
double cumulatedAverages = 0d;

Student[] students = new Student[classSize];

 for(int i =0;i<students.length;i++){
    Student student = new Student();
    // populate student's data
    student.readInfo();
    // make calculations
    student.computeGrade();
    student.computeAverage();
    cumulatedAverages  = cumulatedAverages + student.getAverage();
    // add the student to the array
    students[i] = student;
}

// compute the class average
double classAverage = cumulatedAverages / classSize;

System.out.printf("%s %-3.2f","Class average is",classAverage);

}
```